# Voulme Scatter in World doesn't show up

Tags: volumetrics

When I enable Volume Scatter for the World it doesn't do anything.
There is no Enviroment Texture so that shouldn't be a problem.

I added a cube with the same settings and it does exactly what it should.
[image]
(Nodes are for the Cube.)

Ambient Occlusion doesn't make a difference.
Volume Bounces in Render-->Light Paths is at 4

But I don't want to use a Cube. I want easy fog to experiment around with as a first step.

Comment: play with the values for density

Comment: The easiest fog is mist in the World settings > Mist Pass (shown there only once Mist is enabled in Render layers tab > Passes. Other than that cube with volume shaders is the most correct way for faking volume